# Progress codpage export data to sql via dtsx

Tags: sql, ssis, codepages, progress-db

In our Progress (V9.1B)  the codepage used is ibm8858-1. On a unix sco machine.

In Progress I dump data as follows :
export stream strA to /u/usr/ppd/tesk.txt convert target "1252".

for each tab1 no-lock :
   put tab1.field1 ";" tab1.field2 skip.
end.

When I use vi to open de file is see the french words as follows : Apr\212s in stead of après.

Normally I ftp that file to a PC and then via a dtsx I load it in sql.

But in sql the french characters are also not in the correct format.

Does somebody knows how I have to export the data (text) and how I need to import it in sql (2005) . Now I also use codepage 1252 in my dtsx.

Tkx,
Jac

Answer (score 0):

Are you 100% sure the field doesn't contain "Apr\212s"? I'm also unsure if there is a ibm8858-1 codepage, I'm guessing you might be mixing it up with iso8859-1 (Scandinavian letters).

Whenever I encounter codepage problems the characters are garbled, not converted to something that looks like a ascii code.

You can always try (assuming its really iso8859-1)

convert source "iso8859-1" target "1252".